# How to change KWD currency code to KD in magento2 whole site vise

Tags: magento2

I want to change Currency symbol **KWD to KD** in magento2

**How to make it?**

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the currency symbols as you need to just follow the steps mentioned below.

- Go to Stores >> Currency >> Currency Symbols from Admin panel.
- Insert the custom currency that you want after clearing the Use Standard To
  enable the new symbol just Save Currency Symbols.
- On the system message don’t forget to refresh the cache by clicking the Cache  Management

OR programmatically you can do it by following way.

So create/edit `config.xml` file in any module, add following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Store:etc/config.xsd">
    <default>
        <currency>
            <options>
                <customsymbol>{"KWD":"KD"}</customsymbol>
            </options>
        </currency>
    </default>
</config>
```

AND For currency symbol, you can get it by the following method

**First create helper file with method:**

```
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Directory\Model\CurrencyFactory;

class Data
{
    /**
     * @var StoreManagerInterface
     */
    private $storeConfig;

    /**
     * @var CurrencyFactory
     */
    private $currencyCode;

    /**
     * Currency constructor.
     *
     * @param StoreManagerInterface $storeConfig
     * @param CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
     */
    public function __construct(
        StoreManagerInterface $storeConfig,
        CurrencyFactory $currencyFactory
    ) {
        $this->storeConfig = $storeConfig;
        $this->currencyCode = $currencyFactory->create();
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSymbol()
    {
        $currentCurrency = $this->storeConfig->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();
        $currency = $this->currencyCode->load($currentCurrency);
        return $currency->getCurrencySymbol();
    }
}
```

**Now call your helper file in your .phtml**

```
$this->helper('Vendor\Module\Helper\Data')->getSymbol();
```

Comment: Yes i have tried this already... but this is not working in currency switcher

Comment: \Magento\Directory\Block\Currency $block
$block->getCurrentCurrencyCode()
it's default one

Comment: Ohh I see, so now you need to get it by any helper method or override your Magento\Directory\Block\Currency block and get currency symbol by currency model, please check my updated answer for more information

Comment: Sorry but i am able to see any logic in your code which changing "KWD" to "KD"

Comment: But I have to change code

Comment: I don't think this can be possible, if you want to show the code then you just need to add hard code condition in your .phtml or block like `if ( $code == "KWD") $code = "KD" `

Comment: @RutveeSojitra did you get the solution?

Comment: not in logical way

Comment: Yes because it seems not possible logically!

Comment: Yes what you give as suggestion i can think it directly i don't have to put magento questions for it.
when i am asking here it means i am digging for magento solution.
If you want to accept your answer so I can !! But it will not right be for others

Comment: Yes exactly, no need to accept my answer, just delete your question, because it's not needed and it will not help others